# What are some good Entity Framework Alternatives

Tags: c#, sql, orm

I am using the Entity Framework now and constantly having to write inline sql because Entity framework does not support full text search and other features. Is there a ORM out there that has many features that supports advanced queries? I feel if I am going to sometimes write inline sql I might as well do all of it in inline sql. Any help here

Comment: Just my two cents, ... but if you want advanced queries you could simply dump the ORM idea, and use inline sql instead, and keep an eye on separation of your persistency layer code and business logic (which does not mean having objects which represent tables in your db, but objects that represent an intent which in turn transparently read and write to the database behind the curtain). Similar to active record, but nearer to the intent.

Comment: Luke101's opinions here are interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691575/what-orm-for-net-should-i-use/1691790#1691790

Comment: EntityWorker.Core is new and kind of like EntityFramework with more functionality and much faster then entityframework. https://github.com/AlenToma/EntityWorker.Core

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at:

- [LINQ queries in DataObjects.Net](http://dataobjectsdotnet.googlecode.com/hg/Manual/05-Queries.htm). If you're interesting in most complex parts, start from the tail.
- [Advanced LINQ in DataObjects.Net](http://dataobjectsdotnet.googlecode.com/hg/Manual/11-AdvancedLinq.htm). Some underlying SQL queries are shown there.

Comment: Forgot to add: there is no full-text search yet. But this is on the way, see e.g. http://forum.x-tensive.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=5657 for some details.

Comment: DataObjects.Net has very poor LINQ implementation and performs VERY slowly. I would strongly recommend using NHibernate instead as a direct comparison - it does everything DO.Net does and does everything better.

Comment: That's wrong - it's enough to look at supported features to see the difference. So I'd like to hear a proof of this; on contrary, I can easily prove LINQ in NH does not support _lots_ of features supported by DO & other ORM tools (see e.g. tests @ ORMBattle.NET); the same about performance.

Comment: Just an easy proof you're wrong: http://goo.gl/s2gvP (check out the whole section and compare this to NH).

Comment: Page links are still broken.

Answer (score 12):

[NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) is one of the bigger OR/M alternatives and Open Source that I like. It is can do some pretty "advanced" things but has a steep learning curve.

Comment: LINQ support there is, well, among the worst ones.

Answer (score 7):

> I feel if I am going to sometimes write inline sql I might as well do all of it in inline sql

Seriously?  When using any ORM, you're always going to hit situations where it is better, cleaner, or more performant, to use SQL or call a stored proc.  You shouldn't just blindly trust it do absolutely everything for you in all situations.

Comment: "If I have to write this procedure in assembly for really good performance, I might as well write the rest of my app in assembly too..."

Comment: For that matter just too damn complicated to do it in ORM, try select statements with 20 tables and sub queries. It's just simpler in sql sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

[Mindscape LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx) is an o/r mapper for .NET that [supports full text search](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/lightspeed/Help/Help%20Topics/LightSpeed/SearchEngine.html) (via Lucene but extensible so you could add your own).

It also supports LINQ, has a [Visual Studio integrated designer](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/lightspeed/features/designer.aspx) with full schema round tripping so you can work model-first or database-first - whichever takes your fancy :-)

There is also a free version that you can use to decide if it is right for you.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

You might look [CodeFluent Entities](http://www.softfluent.com/products/codefluent-entities) but you need to understand that it does not internally rely on any ORM or third party tool.

Entity Framework is an ORM whereas CodeFluent Entities is a full model-first
software factory. It uses a natural and visual modeling approach (like Entity Framework and integrated into Visual Studio) and can generate database scripts, object oriented data layer - code (C#, VB), web services and even UIs components.

Answer (score 4):

Most ORMs will still require some inline SQL every now and then.  NHibernate, Linq 2 Sql, etc. don't support full text search out of the box (NHibernate has NHibernate.Search which uses Lucene.NET to perform full text search, Linq 2 Sql has access to stored procedures that you can create that use full text search).

This doesn't mean you should scrap using an ORM altogether though.  There's a *ton* of repetitive plumbing code that ORMs can save you from writing and the general use cases are all relatively easy to execute (e.g. CRUD operations) with any ORM.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at [LLBLGen Pro](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) or Telerik's [OpenAccess](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx), but NHibernate is going to be the solution with the largest community around it.

Comment: Does LLBLGen Pro have good performance?

Comment: LLBLGen Pro is one of the fastest ORMs out there: https://github.com/FransBouma/RawDataAccessBencher

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of [SubSonic](https://github.com/subsonic) by Rob Conery.  It is (was) simple and easy to set up and use.

Comment: Site is dead and redirects to spam.

Comment: set the link to the git repo.

Answer (score 2):

Like most people here I'd recommend NHibernate, but you may want to look into using it in conjunction with [CastleProject's ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html) implementation.  NHibernate by itself can take a bit of getting used to, but when you throw ActiveRecord on top of it things get a lot easier.  I was able to do an EntityFramework->NHibernate/ActiveRecord conversion really quickly.

Comment: Are there any books or really good tutorials on nhibernate/activeRecored? Also, do you think the lifespan of active record will be high? I am expecting support for at leat 10 years. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not really, which is sort of a pain, but also sort of a non issue.  It's really easy to do the majority of db integration with Active Record/NHibernate, and the Castle tutorials online pretty much give you all you need to know.  If the Castle site is lacking then a quick Google/Bing search will result in you finding lot of people out there blogging about stuff they've figured out how to do with it.

As far as how long it will be around.  Its open source so you don't have to worry about it "going away", just take the source and compile it yourself, then you'll always have it.

Answer (score 1):

Seconding what the others said, nHibernate.  Plus I found [this link](http://theresidentalien.typepad.com/ginormous/2006/10/full_text_searc.html) re: full text search and nHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [nHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate)?

If you search for [nHibernate and full text search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_en-USUS293US304&q=nHibernate+full+text+search&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) you'll come up with a variety of links that talk about that particular type of search implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [nHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html)