# Best Data Access Model for WinForms applications

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-access-layer, data-access

Which data-access model has the best performance and speed for a C# Winforms application?

- Dataset?
- NHibernate?
- Entity Framework?

Why would people say not to use Datasets ?

Comment: The best way is to roll your own data layer in assembly.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691575/what-orm-for-net-should-i-use

Comment: I need to know which flavor of ice cream is the best. Chocolate? Vanilla? Strawberry? Please help me to choose the best...

Comment: There is no best, each different has its pros and cons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really doesn't matter.  The true cost is in I/O, getting the query to the dbase engine and getting the results back.  And getting them painted to the screen in the case of WinForms.  Whacking the bits into an object model is a fraction of a percent of the overall cost.