# Which ORM does fit best here?

Tags: c#, .net, orm

I need to choose an ORM for a project and I only have some experience with NHibernate. I have been reading Q&A from StackOverflow, and the most similar to my needs is [What ORM for .net should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691575/what-orm-for-net-should-i-use?rq=1), but I would like to have an answer more adequate to the present products (the link is from 2009) and that also take into account some points of my project.

The easiest solution for me would be to use NHibernate because it is mature, feature rich and I have already used it, but I prefer to choose the best option for the project even if I have to "study" again.

The project is going to start as a core that communicates with SAP. The core has to support standalone and/or co-dependent modules, and each one of them may need to work with its own data from the database. The final step will be to implement the part of SAP that we use. The characteristics I need are the ones from the previous link and here are some more things to have in mind:

- I would like to be able to split the data access layer so that a user with one or two modules won't need the whole thing.
- A designer would be appreciated.
- It will start with about 20-30 tables and, within a couple of years, that number will grow in several hundreds.
- The amount of registers per table will vary from two or three to 150000+ (very few).
- IT DOES NOT NEED TO BE A ONE PRODUCT SOLUTION. Combinations like NHibernate and Devart Entity Develop are also welcome.
- The team for this project will also have students that will have to learn C Sharp and some of them probably don´t know exactly what an ORM is, so it would be great if it is simple or, at least, the basic stuff is not very complex (mixing tons of lambdas, reflection, extension methods, etc.).

The last one is not very important. I hope this is specific enough to avoid been closed (the question I link is still open).

EDIT:
-It is a desktop application.
-Documentation and comunity are also very very important.

Comment: You never explained why you're convinced that ORM is the right solution for you. Also, is this a web or desktop project?

Comment: I think ORM is the right solution mainly because it will have to work with different databases.

Comment: There's a great article by Jeff Atwood here on why ORM is not a good solution in general. It links to a long essay that has much more details. Take a look and know what you're getting into: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/06/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science.html

Comment: @ashes999 Of course the ORM brings some problems, but the article date is June 26, 2006. Things have change since then and if I have to coordinate the work of inexperienced students and programmers with 10+ years of experience in FoxPro that are used to have code and queries in the same "screen" file and that now are going to begin using C#, I preffer to impose a single way to access database and I like the ORM approach.

Comment: Okay, if that's what you want to think, go for it. ORM still suffers from many of the problems outlined in that article and post (I've tried with modern ORMs since 2010). Just understand what you're getting into, it's not a silver bullet.

Comment: @ashes999 I appreciate your opinion and I have been able to read the article more carefully. The problems he mentions are widely known. One of the “solutions” he talks about is LINQ which, nowadays, is everywhere in .Net. The RowSet/DataSet thing, would solve some problems and create new ones... I have no time to study, design a implement other choices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate, entity framework, active records or linq2sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most popular ORM for .Net these days is Entity Framework. It comes from Microsoft, so well documented in MSDN style. And it fits your criteria.

I worked with NHibernate and found that documentation is patchy, inconsistent and sometimes missing. Most of the time I had to use docs for Hibernate which were not for NHibernate, just similar.

EF can do the same things and more than NHibernate, and the latest release have Migrations, which was missing (when I worked with NHibernate).

Comment: I guess so. Only started EF recently and did not encounter a problem with lack of documentation, unlike with NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Consider it Dapper: [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

Dapper is a pretty simple ORM, developed and used by StackOverflow.

There is a lack of documentation, but that is because of it simplicity. You can find some usage example in the project page or in some websites like [this](http://2ndimension.net/blog/?p=302).

Comment: +1.  @CarlosJ - You mentioned, "I think ORM is the right solution mainly because it will have to work with different databases."  If this is the case, something lightweight & efficient like Dapper is going to have a nice advantage.  I mean, often times with EF I'll write stored procedures to squeeze more performance out of my queries, and then I'll add the stored proc to the EF model.  But if the intention is to build something that's database agnostic then writing stored procedures all the time won't be a good strategy.

Comment: talles and @Steve Wortham Thanks, I will take a look at it, but the last item is NOT very important because I can handle the complex part at the begining.

Comment: @CarlosJ Oh, I'm sorry, I though I read that IS very important.

Comment: Talles and @Steve Wortham: Does Dapper cover the rest of the exposed criteria (and the characteristics from the other question)?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old question, but I though I would post an answer for anyone who lands here.  Check out [SQL Data](http://sqldata.codeplex.com).  It is extremely simple to use, very powerful and fits all the OP's requirements.